# How to assure that filehandle.write() does not fail due to str/bytes conversions issues?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, filehandle

I need to detect if a filehandle is using binary mode or text mode - this is required in order to be able to encode/decode str/bytes. How can I do that?

When using binary mode `myfile.write(bytes)` works, and when in text mode `myfile.write(str)` works.

The idea is that I need to know this in order to be able to encode/decode the argument before calling myfile.write(), otherwise it may fail with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about solving your problem this way:

```
try:
    f.write(msg)
except TypeError:
    f.write(msg.encode("utf-8"))
```

This will work even if your handle does not provide a `.mode`.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.mode

```
>>> f = open("blah.txt", "wb")
>>> f
<open file 'blah.txt', mode 'wb' at 0x0000000001E44E00>
>>> f.mode
'wb'
>>> "b" in f.mode
True
```

With this caveat:

> file.mode
>
> The I/O mode for the file. If the file was created using the open()
> built-in function, this will be the
> value of the mode parameter. This is a
> read-only attribute and **may not be
> present on all file-like objects.**

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy, I voted your answer but selected the other response because it is a better solution for my problem (let's say that it is more pythonic).